# How to make flask handle 25k request per second like express.js

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

So i am making a big social media app but i have a problem which framework to choose flask or express.js i like flask so much but it cant handle too much requests. Express.js can handle about 25k request per second (google). So is there anyway to make flask handle 25k request per second using gunicorn currently i am using this command `$ gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 your_project:app` but it can only handle 4 request at a time. And uh one more question can flask handle 1Million user at a time. Should i choose express.js because it can handle 25k request

Comment: This seems like a XY problem. It also sounds like a theoretical question instead of a question based on a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multithreads or gevent to increase gunicorn's concurrency.

### Option1 multithreads

eg:

```sh
gunicorn -w 4 --threads 100 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 your_project:app
```

`--threads 100` means 100 threads per process.

`-w 4` means 4 processes, so `-w 4 --threads 100` means 400 requests at a time

### Option2 gevent worker

eg:

```sh
pip install gevent
gunicorn -w 4 -k gevent --worker-connections 1000 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 your_project:app
```

`-k gevent --worker-connections 1000` means 1000 coroutines per gevent worker process.

`-w 4` means 4 processes, so `-w 4 -k gevent --worker-connections 1000` means 4000 requests at a time.

For more information, you can refer to my blog post: https://easydevguide.com/posts/gunicorn_concurrency